# CodenameOne: Error sending build to codename one build server

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

I am using eclipse
**Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
Build id: 20210910-1417**
with Ant. Upon trying to send any build to the codename one build server via the context menu shown below

[image]

I receive the following Java compiler error:

> [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (19.0.2). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
> [javac] java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCConstantCaseLabel cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral (com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCConstantCaseLabel and com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral are in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app')
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.visitLiteral(TreeDiffer.java:425)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral.accept(JCTree.java:2692)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitConstantCaseLabel(TreeScanner.java:316)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCConstantCaseLabel.accept(JCTree.java:2327)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:146)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:161)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.visitCase(TreeDiffer.java:297)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCase.accept(JCTree.java:1328)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:146)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:161)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.visitSwitch(TreeDiffer.java:532)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCSwitch.accept(JCTree.java:1287)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:146)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:161)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.visitBlock(TreeDiffer.java:279)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TreeDiffer.scan(TreeDiffer.java:146)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod$DedupedLambda.equals(LambdaToMethod.java:207)
> [javac]     at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:641)
> [javac]     at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1152)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitLambda(LambdaToMethod.java:396)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1976)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitApply(TreeTranslator.java:291)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1799)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitExec(TreeTranslator.java:256)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1586)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitIf(TreeTranslator.java:250)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1555)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitLambda(LambdaToMethod.java:391)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1976)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitApply(TreeTranslator.java:291)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1799)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitExec(TreeTranslator.java:256)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1586)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitIf(TreeTranslator.java:250)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1555)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitIf(TreeTranslator.java:250)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1555)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitIf(TreeTranslator.java:250)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1555)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1082)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitMethodDef(TreeTranslator.java:150)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:912)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitClassDef(TreeTranslator.java:139)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitClassDef(LambdaToMethod.java:307)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:810)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translateTopLevelClass(LambdaToMethod.java:287)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1560)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1426)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:946)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:317)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:176)
> [javac]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:64)
> [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> [javac]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:57)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1388)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1117)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
> [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> [javac]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:34)
> [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
> [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:712)
> [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:532)
> [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> [javac]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
> [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:374)
> [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:476)
> [javac]     at codenameoneplugin.actions.SendBuild$1.run(SendBuild.java:47)
> [javac]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
> [javac] printing javac parameters to: C:\WINDOWS\system32\javac.20230306_120937.args

I have Five other codename one projects in this workspace that are all working without issue. Also, the jar Ant task also works without issues. The problem only happens when trying to send the build to the codename one server. Completely baffled as to what is going on here. Has anyone encountered this before? If not, any suggestions on how to go about diagnosing the issue?

**EDIT**

As you can see below the jar builds locally without issue. Why is it trying to use java compiler 19.0.2 when sending to codename one when I've never even installed that on my system?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is for legacy projects only. We [migrated to maven](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html) a few years back. You should start with https://start.codenameone.com/

Having said that the problem will happen there too. You need to use JDK 11. Not a newer JDK. Newer JDKs dropped support to older features that we need.

Comment: Thanks Shai, however I have 5 other projects that all work without issue. Furthermore, the project builds locally without issue. Migrating 6 projects is not a valid short term solution, if something breaks I need the ability to fix that issue in the short term. I am planning to migrate the projects to maven, but again if five other projects work and this one doesn't that is a good indication theres an actual solution to my current problem. Any suggestions for me to try?

Comment: Sure, that's why we haven't removed the plugins from the stores. I guess this is something that's builtin to a newer version of Eclipse that got in the way. Notice the last line: C:\WINDOWS\system32\javac.20230306_120937.args which seems to indicate this is something global in the system. Check the environment and global java command.